# mgo.v2 Find().Select().One() returns blank

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

The mongo shell output

```
> db.departments.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5733b051e444917f9d273ce6"), "id" : "5733b05157659a11a4589102", "brandid" : "1", "name" : "first", "managerid" : "0", "users" : [ "1", "2", "3", "7" ] }
```

The function takes depID as input which I verified is exactly what it should be i.e. `5733b05157659a11a4589102`

```
func GetUsers(depID string) (*department.UsersResp, error) {
    if !bson.IsObjectIdHex(depID) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s is not a ObjectId value", depID)
    }
    type UserResp struct {
        users []string 
    }
    var result *UserResp
    err := coll.Find(bson.M{"id": depID}).Select(bson.M{"users": 1}).One(&result)

    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err, result)
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("result:",result)
    //ignore return type and value the above print is what i have doubt about
    return result, nil
}
```

the out put of result comes `{[]}`

i have tried the following queries other that above
`err := coll.Find(bson.M{"id": depID})One(&result)`
`err := coll.Find(nil).One(&result)`
the result is same.

everything is fine with db connection and other things as all the other functions of the same file using the same variable `coll` works

*More Info*
Also I have tried this

```
type UserResp struct {
   users []string `json:"users" bson:"users"`
}
```

Mongo LOG

```
MGO: cluster.go:590: Cluster has 1 known masters and 0 known slaves.
MGO: socket.go:391: Socket 0xc8201340e0 to 127.0.0.1:27017: serializing op: &mgo.queryOp{collection:"departments.departments", query:bson.M{"id":"5733b05157659a11a4589102"}, skip:0, limit:-1, selector:bson.M{"users":1}, flags:0x4, replyFunc:(mgo.replyFunc)(0x58eef0), mode:1, options:mgo.queryWrapper{Query:interface {}(nil), OrderBy:interface {}(nil), Hint:interface {}(nil), Explain:false, Snapshot:false, ReadPreference:bson.D(nil), MaxScan:0, MaxTimeMS:0, Comment:""}, hasOptions:false, serverTags:[]bson.D(nil)}
MGO: socket.go:521: Socket 0xc8201340e0 to 127.0.0.1:27017: sending 1 op(s) (106 bytes)
MGO: socket.go:311: Socket 0xc8201340e0 to 127.0.0.1:27017: updated write deadline to 1m0s ahead (2016-05-12 10:18:17.811427695 -0400 EDT)
MGO: socket.go:311: Socket 0xc8201340e0 to 127.0.0.1:27017: updated read deadline to 1m0s ahead (2016-05-12 10:18:17.811468447 -0400 EDT)
MGO: socket.go:563: Socket 0xc8201340e0 to 127.0.0.1:27017: got reply (106 bytes)
MGO: socket.go:622: Socket 0xc8201340e0 to 127.0.0.1:27017: received document: bson.M{"_id":"W3\xb0Q\xe4D\x91\u007f\x9d'<\xe6", "users":[]interface {}{"1", "2", "3", "7"}}
MGO: session.go:3062: Query 0xc82012c000 document unmarshaled: &db.UserResp{users:[]string(nil)}
{[]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue may be that your UserResp struct has private members.

```
//Instead of
 users []string `json:"users" bson:"users"`

// Try
 Users []string `json:"users" bson:"users"`
```

Comment: @RohitHazra, this solution works for me (note capital `Users`). Can you confirm that you have tried this ? cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, but maybe try

```
var result UserResp
```

instead of using a pointer.

Also as **Walt** mentioned, you should export the `Users` field as well.

Answer (score -1):

1. `users` isn't exported, it should be `Users`.
2. You don't need a pointer to a pointer, I'd personally just use `var result UserResp`.

Corrections below:

```
type UserResp struct {
    Users []string 
}
var result UserResp
err := coll.Find(bson.M{"id": depID}).Select(bson.M{"users": 1}).One(&result)
```

If those aren't the issues, I've had plenty of issues dealing with BSON and arrays/slices. You could try making `Users` a slice of interface, or just write the whole output to a bson.M map (`map[string]interface{}`) and go from there. Here's how I would do that:

```
var result bson.M
err := coll.Find(bson.M{"id": depID}).Select(bson.M{"users": 1}).One(&result)
```

You can access the underlying data with a type assertion:

```
result["users"].([]string)
```

If that doesn't work simply examine the underlying data to debug the returned type:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", result)
```

Either way, once you have the data in Go like this. It will be much easier to debug.